# WMLS file not detected when called

Tags: wml

I have a wml and wmls file both in the same directory , I am using winwap to run my script.

in my wml file I call a function in the wmls file in the following fashion

```
<a href="validateForm.wmls#validate()">Submit Form Data</a>
```

my wmls file named validateForm.wmls has the following function

```
extern function validate()
```

I keep getting this error that the file location of the wmls is not found

1) I have kept both the files in the same folder
2) in the declaration the file name seems correct

I am unsure why this error occurs . Any help would be appreciated . THank ou

Answer (score 0):

Did you compile your WMLScript?, usually you should call it from the compiled version

```
<a href="validateForm.wmls**c**#validate()">Submit Form Data</a>
```

Also if your device supports local storage and you downloaded the file locally, is usefull to specify the path (in devices running POSWEB, VERIWEB, and similar):

```
<a href="**f:**validateForm.wmls**c**#validate()">Submit Form Data</a>
```

If not, it may happen that the browser is loading the file from cache or another location.

Hope it helps you, I had that issue long time ago.